# Change float values into integer values and then concatenate in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named "sample" which has three columns: "birthDay", "birthMonth" and "birthYear" and containing float values as in following picture:

[image]

I want to add new column "dateOfBirth" and to have entries in integer format and to obtain following data frame:

[image]

I tried `sample["dateOfBirth"] = sample["birthDay"].map(str). +"/"+ baseball["birthMonth"].map(str) +"/"+ baseball["birthYear"].map(str)`. But the result was as `"11.0/3.0/1988.0"` and `"4.0/20.0/2001.0"`.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***setup***

```
sample = pd.DataFrame([
        [3., 11., 1988.],
        [20., 4., 2001.],
    ], columns=['birthDay', 'birthMonth', 'birthYear'])
```

***option 1***
make `dateOfBirth` a series of `Timestamps`

```
# dictionary map to rename to canonical date names
# enables convenient conversion using pd.to_datetime
m = dict(birthDay='Day', birthMonth='Month', birthYear='Year')
sample['dateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(sample.rename(columns=m))

sample
```

[image]

---

***option 2***
If you insist on a string
use the `dt` accessor with `strftime`

```
# dictionary map to rename to canonical date names
# enables convenient conversion using pd.to_datetime
m = dict(birthDay='Day', birthMonth='Month', birthYear='Year')

sample['dateOfBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(sample.rename(columns=m)) \
                          .dt.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')

sample
```

[image]

---

***option 3***
If you really want to reconstruct from the values
using `apply`

```
f = '{birthMonth:0.0f}/{birthDay:0.0f}/{birthYear:0.0f}'.format
sample['dateOfBirth'] = sample.apply(lambda x: f(**x), 1)
sample
```

[image]

---

***nulls***
In the event that one or more of the date columns has a missing value:
Options 1 and 2 don't require any changes and are the recommended options anyway.
If you want to construct from floats, we can use a boolean mask and `loc` to assign.

```
sample = pd.DataFrame([
        [3., 11., 1988.],
        [20., 4., 2001.],
        [20., np.nan, 2001.],
    ], columns=['birthDay', 'birthMonth', 'birthYear'])

sample
```

[image]

```
f = '{birthMonth:0.0f}/{birthDay:0.0f}/{birthYear:0.0f}'.format
mask = sample[['birthDay', 'birthMonth', 'birthYear']].notnull().all(1)
sample.loc[mask, 'dateOfBirth'] = sample.apply(lambda x: f(**x), 1)
sample
```

[image]

---

***timing***
***given sample***
[image]

***timing***
***given sample times 10,000***
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and for your time typing it piRSquared.

Answer (score 1):

Before you begin your string concatenation convert all columns to int and then to str.

```
df = df.astype(int).astype(str)
df['dateOfBirth'] = df['birthMonth'] + '/' + df['birthDay'] + '/' + df['birthYear']
```

Comment: what if one of colums, lets say "birthDay", contains "NA" value. If I try df = df.astype(int) it raises an error.

Comment: NumPy unfortunately has no missing value for integers. If a column has at least one missing value then it will be a float. Since these rows don't contain valid days, they won't form date of births so you might need to filter them out and add them back in with a missing value for the date of birth.

Comment: I really appreciate Ted. It makes a lot of sense to me.